# How to use incomplete LU factorization in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have read the [docs of IncompleteLUT](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1IncompleteLUT.html)

And show the detail here:

> - Classes
>
>   ```
>   struct    keep_diag
>   ```
> - Public Member Functions
>
>   ```
>   template< typename MatrixType >
>   IncompleteLUT< Scalar > & compute (const MatrixType &amat)
>             ComputationInfo info () const`
>                        void setDroptol (const RealScalar &droptol)`
>                        void setFillfactor (int fillfactor)`
>   ```

But I am puzzling how to use the method to get the result matrix 
of incomplete LU factorization. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document in development branch is a little bit more clear.

> This class follows the sparse solver concept .

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1IncompleteLUT.html

The class `IncompleteLUT` follows the concept of Sparse Solver.  All Sparse Solvers have the same interface as shown in the linked tutorial.  Basically you only need to replace the `SolverClassName` with the desired solver name , in this case `IncompleteLUT`.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html#TutorialSparseSolverConcept

Comment: Thank you, but my matrix is `MatrxXd` not `SparseMatrx`, does that matters?

Comment: @AlexanderYau Of course... They are in different chapters. You need dense solvers. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__DenseLinearSolvers__chapter.html